# How to process webhook request coming from a 3rd party application?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need help to evaluate weather i am doing it right or is there a better way, the scenario is an 3rd party application is sending an webhook request after a successful payment but the problem is that sometimes this application  may send the same notification more than once.so it is recommended to ensure that implementation of the webhook is idempotent.so steps that i am implementing for this are
if signature is correct (assume it is corect),Find orders record in the  database using orderId in the request params.
Please note: orderId in request params is payment_gateway_order_identifier in orders table.
if txStatus = 'SUCCESS' AND haven't already processed COLLECTION payment for this same order,
Create payments record.
201 response with nothing in the response body.
else
201 response with nothing in the response body.
else
422 response with {message: "Signature is incorrect"} in response body

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])

    def cashfree_request(request):                
        if request.method == 'POST':    
            data=request.POST.dict()
            payment_gateway_order_identifier= data['orderId'] 
            amount = data['orderAmount']
            transaction_status = data['txStatus'] 
            signature = data['signature']
            if(computedsignature==signature): #assume it to be true
                order=Orders.objects.get(
                         payment_gateway_order_identifier=payment_gateway_order_identifier)
                if transaction_status=='SUCCESS':
                    try:
                        payment= Payments.objects.get(orders=order)
                        return Response({"Payment":"Done"},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                    except (Payments.DoesNotExist):
                        payment = Payments(orders=order,amount=amount,datetime=datetime)
                        payment.save()
                        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)      
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
```

models.py

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4)
    payment_gateway_order_identifier = models.UUIDField(
                                     primary_key=False,default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False,unique=True) 
  sussessfull
   
class Payments(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    orders = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4, verbose_name='Price in INR')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This rather belongs to [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Anyway - you are doing up to 3 consecutive SQL queries, so there's a chance for a race condition. A simple way how to prevent that: use some KV storage like Redis/Memcache as a lock - save the value you're using as a *nonce* on the start of the function, and delete it on the end.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def cashfree_request(request):
    data = request.POST.dict()
    payment_gateway_order_identifier = data['orderId']

    # `nx` will set & return only if the key does not exist
    # set a timeout in case it wont reach `delete()` on the end 
    if not redis.set("lock_%s" % payment_gateway_order_identifier, "1", nx=True, ex=2):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)

    amount = data['orderAmount']
    transaction_status = data['txStatus']
    signature = data['signature']
    if computedsignature == signature:
        order = Orders.objects.get(payment_gateway_order_identifier=payment_gateway_order_identifier)

        if transaction_status == 'SUCCESS':
            try:
                Payments.objects.get(orders=order)
                res = Response({"Payment": "Done"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except Payments.DoesNotExist:
                payment = Payments(orders=order, amount=amount, datetime=datetime)
                payment.save()
                res = Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        res = Response(status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    
    # unlock for another request
    redis.delete("lock_%s" % payment_gateway_order_identifier)
    return res
```

- you dont need `if request.method == 'POST':` since the code is accessible via POST only anyway, that will make your code less indented.
- notice you dont handle the case where `transaction_status` is not `SUCCESS`

Comment: Thnanks a lot  @yedpodtrzitko for the help and suggestions.